# Convert a foreach loop to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

`ModelBeams` is a `List<ModelBeam>` and `linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection` is a `List<double>`.

How can I write the below `foreach` loop using `LINQ`?

```
foreach (var beam in ModelBeams)
{
    linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection.Add(beam.ConnectivityLine.I.Y);
    linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection.Add(beam.ConnectivityLine.J.Y);
}
```

Comment: Which version of .NET? I believe the ForEach extension method was added later

Comment: Why would you want to? I think it reads pretty well what you have, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Default I know, I was just curious because it is bugging me since morning  :p

Comment: Could you use the .AddRange() function in some way? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336770(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Linq to select the two pieces as a collection, then use SelectMany to "flatten" the collection:

```
linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection.AddRange(
   ModelBeams.SelectMany(beam => new [] {
                                         beam.ConnectivityLine.I.Y, 
                                         beam.ConnectivityLine.J.Y}
                        ));
```

Comment: Thanks D Stanley, this is the correct answer. Is this faster than `foreach` in this case?

Comment: @Vahid I highly doubt it considering that you'll be creating an array for each item. Your conventional `for each` will likely be faster than anything you receive as an alternate suggestion.

Comment: @Vahid For readability I would keep the original code. Also this does not give any performance change (for the better).

Comment: I'll stick to the readable solution, I was just curious about how `LINQ` this.

Comment: @Vahid you will have some overhead for creating the array, but I wouldn't expect to be significant.  Use whatever you find most readable, and only optimize for performance if it makes a significant, measurable contribution to the overall performance of the system (i.e. don't guess).

Comment: Thanks Stanley, I totally agree specially about the guessing part which most of the time we get it wrong when it comes to optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection
    .AddRange(ModelBeams.SelectMany(mb => new double[] {mb.ConnectivityLine.I.Y,
                                                       mb.ConnectivityLine.J.Y})
             );
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ModelBeams.ForEach(mb => 
{
    linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection.Add(mb.ConnectivityLine.I.Y);
    linesPassingThroughBeamEndsInYDirection.Add(mb.ConnectivityLine.J.Y);
});
```

Comment: [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already exists

Comment: @AmirPopovich but it exists for `List<T>` which is the structure the op is using.